# Running meta: refresh_inventory in a loop?

Tags: ansible, libvirt

I'm using Ansible with a [dynamic inventory plugin](https://github.com/larsks/libvirt_inventory_plugin) to build some virtual machines in libvirt. After creating the machines, I need to wait for them to acquire an ip address.  I can't simply do this:

```
- wait_for_connection:
```

Because immediately after the virtual machines are created, they won't have an ip address. What I need to do is this:

```
- name: wait until node has acquired an address
  meta: refresh_inventory
  until: ansible_host|ipaddr
  retries: 30
  delay: 1

- name: wait until node has finished booting
  wait_for_connection:
```

That is, I need to wait until the inventory information for each host includes an address in `ansible_host`.  Unfortunately, the above task doesn't work: it simply executes once and continues.

I could just hardcode a delay:

```
- pause:
    seconds: 30
```

But I would love to have a more active check here to avoid unnecessary delays (and problems if something takes longer than expected).

Comment: Unfortunately, the [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html) seems clear on the subject: `Looping on meta tasks is not supported.`. So I guess the `until` loop falls in that category. Have you considered looping on an include that would contains the meta task first and setting a fact until that fact is true ? Kindof a workarround but might be worth a try...

Comment: It turns out that you can't use `until` on a `include_tasks`, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around with it a bit, this is what I ended up doing:

```
- hosts: ovn
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: wait for nodes to acquire addresses
      delegate_to: localhost
      command: >-
        ansible-inventory --host {{ inventory_hostname }}
      register: nodecheck
      changed_when: false
      until: >-
        (nodecheck.stdout|from_json).ansible_host|default('')|ipaddr
      retries: 30
      delay: 1

    - meta: refresh_inventory
```

This repeatedly calls `ansible-inventory --host <host>`, which outputs inventory information for `<host>` in JSON format. We parse that, look for `ansible_host`, and verity that it's an ip address.

Once we know that the inventory source is able to report an ip address for all the nodes, we then call `refresh_inventory`.